# Grouping records based on conditions and retrieving related values in Laravel MYSQL

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two records in the 'holla_voucher_code' table.
Record A has columns: `'group_id', 'group_id_verify', 'export_id', 'id_voucher_verify'`.

Record B has columns: `'group_id', 'group_id_verify', 'export_id', 'id_voucher_verify'`.

Record A has the value of `'id_voucher_verify'` equal to the ID of Record B.
Record B has the value of `'id_voucher_verify'` equal to the ID of Record A.

However, for Record A, the value of `'group_id_verify'` is 0.
For Record B, the value of `'group_id_verify'` is not 0.

I want to group the records by the following three columns: `'export_id', 'group_id', and 'group_id_verify'`. Additionally, if the value of the `'voucher_id_verify'` column is not 0, I want to retrieve the value of the `'group_id'` column from the related record using the `'id_voucher_verify'` relationship.

Could you please assist me in constructing the query to achieve this?

My Code

```
$group_voucher_out_stock = CodeModel::getDBTable();
        $group_voucher_out_stock = $group_voucher_out_stock->select(CodeModel::getDBConn()->raw('COUNT(id) as num'),
            'group_id', 'group_id_verify', 'export_id')
            ->groupBy(['export_id', 'group_id', CodeModel::getDBConn()->raw('IF(`voucher_id_verify` != 0, (SELECT `group_id` FROM `holla_voucher_code` AS A WHERE `A`.`id` = `voucher_id_verify`), `group_id_verify`)')])
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where it is really useful to see your database mapping, smth like database schema of mentioned tables and relations. From what i understood (and i tried to understand rly hard, the part about additional condition i understood that u want to replace the value of group_id with the one from related entity) i think ur looking for smth like:

```
$vouchers = CodeModel::with('voucher')
->get()
->map(function ($voucher) {
    if ($voucher->id_voucher_verify != 0 && $voucher->voucher != null) {
        $voucher->group_id = $voucher->voucher->group_id;
    }
    return $voucher;
})
->groupBy(['export_id', 'group_id', 'group_id_verify']);
```

It gives you some idea of what you should do, just update with good relations. What is going on actually is that code eager loads whole table, checks if id_voucher_verify is not 0 or null (i guess u need this but u asked just for 0 so adjust to your needs), and then returns grouped by the fields that u asked for.